How fix the AttributeError in Gspread
I use gspread and I watched multiprocessing recently. If I want in one time get values, the program falls with error AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute '_auth_request'.
I no idea how it does work.
My code:
batch_data = wks.worksheets()
batch_data.pop(-1)
batch_data.pop(-1)
def f(i):
    return i.get("C31:D90")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(33).map(f, batch_data)

and returns error:
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Krona.py", line 12, in f
    return i.get("C31:D90")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "gspread/worksheet.py", line 952, in get
    response = self.client.values_get(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "gspread/http_client.py", line 236, in values_get
    r = self.request("get", url, params=params)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/gspread/http_client.py", line 114, in request
    response = self.session.request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 526, in request
    self._auth_request
AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute '_auth_request'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Krona.py", line 16, in <module>
    p = Pool(2).map(f,batch_data)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "multiprocessing/pool.py", line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute '_auth_request'

I wait list of values
(I cut off full links to better review)

I have to apologize for my poor English skills. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect in order for me to understand your question correctly? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

@Tanaike My english also not better. Variable 'i' get worksheet  from 'batch_data' and method .get() should get list of article in range "C31:D90". With multiprocessing, I want do it in one moment.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

@Tanaike What do you not understand?
